# Pólya Enumeration Theorem and its Applications

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics

What 'scholarly' sources are out there regarding Pólya's enumeration theorem? I've found a few things, but none of them really give me a nice statement, or a proof that is explained well. Also looking for a few simple examples and maybe a hard one so I can even better understand it/ apply it.

Comment: Have you seen Stanley's book *Enumerative Combinatorics*? I believe volume 1 has something on it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the Wikipedia entry in English quite confusing, but I noticed under the "Talk" tab for that page, the following comment:

> P.S. The Russian wikipedia version is in a sharp contrast with this one, but don't tell me that it is probably my problem with English language comprehension. `'mikka 18:24, 14 March 2007 (UTC)

I followed the link to the Russian version, and in fact the link was broken. However, this seems to be the relevant page from the Russian Wikipedia:

[The Redfield-Polya Theorem (Russian)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B4%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%B8)

Having opened it in Chrome and used Google translate to translate it to English, I find it much clearer and more concise, than the English page, and than the relevant part of Harary's book on Graph Theory.

That page lacks a proof of the PET, but says that

> The proof...is based on Burnside's lemma

and cites two books (apparently in Russian) for this:

Nefedov VN, Osipova VA A course of discrete mathematics. - Moscow : MAI, 1992. - 262 p., p. 157-159

and

Rybnikov K. A. Introduction to combinatorial analysis. - Moscow : Moscow State University, 1972. - 253 p., p. 72-74.